# How we can find the velocity of the box at time 0?

Tags: physics

If we push a box (mass of 2 kilograms) with a force of 4 newton, how we can find the velocity at t= 0 after pushing the box?

i tried:
a=f/M;
then with integration => v(t) - v(0) = f/m * t;
=> v(0) = f/m * t +v(t), but we can't here

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: a=f/M; then with integration => v(t) - v(0) = f/m * t => v(0) = f/m * t +v(t), but we can't here.

Comment: put that in the question

Comment: I think there is some context missing. What is the full problem? Do you know anything else?

Comment: there is a friction so the box will stop, and the box was at rest, thats all what i know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know
$\text{Force}= \text{Mass}\times\text{Acceleration}$

The formula for acceleration is:

$\text{Acceleration} = \dfrac{\text {Force}}{\text{Mass}}$

So, $\text{Acceleration}= \dfrac 42 N = 2N$

Acceleration gives the rate of change of velocity over time. If the box starts from rest $t = 0$, the velocity at $t = 0$ can be calculated using the equation of motion that relates acceleration, initial velocity, time, and displacement:

$\text{Final velocity} = \text{Initial velocity} + \text{Acceleration}\times\text{Time}$

Assuming that the box starts from rest, i.e. $v = 0$:

$\text{Final velocity}= 0 + 2\cdot 0 = 0 m/s$

So, at $t = 0$, the velocity of the box after applying the force is $0$ m/s if it started from rest.

**If it does not start from the rest:**
Without information about the initial velocity of the box or the duration of the applied force, it’s not possible to calculate the velocity of the box at a time after $t=0.$ If the box starts from rest, then its velocity at $t=0$ would be $0$ m/s. But in this case, as you mentioned, the box does not start from rest. Therefore, more information is needed to provide a precise answer.

Comment: yes, but that's not what i want, u calculate the velocity at the rest, but i want the velocity at the hitting time which is the maximum velocity then the velocity start decreasing because the friction.

Comment: Without information about the initial velocity of the box or the duration of the applied force, it’s not possible to calculate the velocity of the box at a time after t=0. If the box starts from rest, then its velocity at t=0 would be 0 m/s. But in this case, as you mentioned, the box does not start from rest. Therefore, more information is needed to provide a precise answer.

Comment: the initial velocity is 0, but what do u mean but duration of the applied force, why the force = 4Nis not enough, what if the 4N force was from another box to make collision, here there is no duration of the applied force.

Comment: I want to said that there is no information of the past before applying the force. If you give information of the force that was applied before t(0) the problem can be solved. Without that, it's impossible to solve for not starting from the rest.

Comment: what is the required information to find v after hiting the box, (the box was at rest).

Comment: if the box was at rest then my solution will work that is mentioned upward

Comment: i mean the v max, the v max is not 0.

Comment: there is no velocity in t=0. In rest t=0 means v=0 too

Comment: but there is a maximum velocity the box can reach before it starts decreasing to 0 again, i want to find the maximum velocity and, this can't be 0. i hope u understand what i want to find.

Comment: its 0 (zero). how can this be possible?

Comment: This is impossible to be 0(zero) because we know that the box changed its position, so it got some speed to change its position.

Comment: but you said that t=0

Comment: Sorry, by t=0 I meant the time at which the speed is maximum

Comment: I misunderstood you, i thought it was zero

Comment: so, you know how to solve find the maximum velocity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150569/discussion-between-aymen-and-samin-mustakim).